# Question about graph laplacian quadratic form

Tags: graph-theory, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, spectral-graph-theory

While I was reading "The Emerging Field of Signal Processing on Graphs," I had a question about the graph Laplacian's quadratic form. The publication claims that
[image]

I am wondering how the left side of equation (sigma form) simplifies to $f^T L f$ (matrix form). How can I recognize similar patterns (sigma form to matrix form) in the future?
Thank you.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "sigma form" and give a definition of $S_p(\mathbf f)$?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to provide the definitions that I encountered in the publication to provide some context to your question. For the remainder of this answer, $G = (V, E, w)$ denotes a weighted graph and $\mathbf f$ a real-valued function on $V$ (referred to as a "signal" in the publication)

> The **edge derivative** of a signal $\mathbf f$ with respect to an edge $e = i \sim j$ at
> vertex $i$ is defined as
> $$
>     \left. \frac{\partial \mathbf f}{\partial e} \right|_i
>     = (\mathbf f(j) - \mathbf f(i)) \sqrt{w(i, j)}
> $$

> The **graph gradient** of $\mathbf f$ at $i \in V$ is the vector $\nabla_i \mathbf f$ with
> $e$-th entry
> $$
>     [\nabla_i \mathbf f](e) = \left. \frac{\partial \mathbf f}{\partial e} \right|_i
> $$

> The **local variation** of $\mathbf f$ at vertex $i$ is
> $$\begin{align*}
>     \left\lVert \nabla_i \mathbf f \right\rVert_2
>     &= \left(
>         \sum_{e \in E} \left(
>             \left. \frac{\partial \mathbf f}{\partial e} \right|_i
>         \right)^2
>     \right)^{1/2} \\
>     &= \left(
>         \sum_{j \sim i} w(i, j) (\mathbf f(j) - \mathbf f(i))^2
>     \right)^{1/2}.
> \end{align*}$$

The local variation is supposed to give some notion of the "smoothness" of a signal near $i$.

> The **discrete $p$-Dirichlet** form is a notion of the global smoothness of a signal
> defined as
> $$\begin{align*}
>     S_p(\mathbf f)
>     &= \frac 1p \sum_{i \in V} \left\lVert \nabla_i \mathbf f \right\rVert^p_2 \\
>     &= \frac 1p \sum_{i \in V} \left(
>         \sum_{j \sim i} w(i, j) (\mathbf f(j) - \mathbf f(i))^2
>     \right)^{p/2}.
> \end{align*}$$

I'm not very familiar with signal processing and I don't know what "sigma form" is, but the definition of the Laplacian matrix is actually based on the Dirichlet form. The Laplacian matrix is typically characterized as $L = D - A$, where $D$ is the degree matrix of a graph and $A$ the adjacency matrix, but its original definition was as a linear operator on the space of functions $V \mapsto \mathbb F$. For a function $\mathbf f: V \to \mathbb F$, the **Laplacian** is defined by the rule
$$
    [L \mathbf f](u) = \sum_{v \sim u} w(u, v) (\mathbf f(u) - \mathbf f(v))
$$
Reasoning that
$$
    \mathbf f^T L \mathbf f
    = \sum_{i \sim j} w(i, j) (\mathbf f(j) - \mathbf f(i))^2 
$$
follows pretty easily. As for why the $1/2$ vanishes, $(i, j)$ and $(j, i)$ are counted as separate edges, so the $1/2$ term accounts for double counting each edge $i \sim j$.

The definition of $L$ as $D - A$ actually came after mathematicians had already defined the Laplacian as a product of boundary operators. There are several texts that explore these concepts further, I recommend the first chapter of Chung's [Spectral Graph Theory](https://bookstore.ams.org/cbms-92/) or section 1.2.1 of the more recent [Higher-Order Systems](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-91374-8).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short algebraic argument. Note that the weighted graph Laplacian is defined in the source as $\mathcal L = D - W$, where $W_{i,j}$ is the weight of the edge between $i$ and $j$ (or $0$ if there is no such edge) and $D$ is the diagonal matrix where $D_{i,i}$ is the sum of weights on edges with endpoint at $i$.

Then
\begin{align}
S_2(\mathbf f) &= \frac12 \sum_{i \in V} \sum_{j \in \mathcal N_i} W_{i,j} [ f(i) - f(j)]^2 \\
&= \frac12 \sum_{i \in V} \sum_{j \in V} W_{i,j} [ f(i) - f(j)]^2 \\
&= \frac12 \sum_{i \in V} \sum_{j \in V} W_{i,j} [f(i)^2 - 2 f(i)f(j) + f(j)^2] \\
&= \frac12 \sum_{i \in V} \sum_{j \in V} W_{i,j} f(i)^2 - \frac12 \sum_{i \in V} \sum_{j \in V} 2 W_{i,j} f(i)f(j) + \frac12 \sum_{i \in V} \sum_{j \in V}   W_{i,j} f(j)^2 \\
&= \frac12 \sum_{i \in V} D_{i,i} f(i)^2 - \sum_{i \in V} \sum_{j \in V} W_{i,j} f(i)f(j) + \frac12 \sum_{j \in V} D_{j,j} f(j)^2 \\
&= \sum_{i \in V} D_{i,i} f(i)^2 - \sum_{i \in V} \sum_{j \in V} W_{i,j} f(i)f(j) \\
&= \mathbf f^{\mathsf T}\! D\mathbf f - \mathbf f^{\mathsf T}W\mathbf f \\
&= \mathbf f^{\mathsf T}\! \mathcal L \mathbf f.
\end{align}

A few notable places where justification could be useful:

- We can replace the sum over $j \in \mathcal N_i$ by a sum over $j \in V$ because $W_{i,j}$ will be $0$ in cases where $j \notin \mathcal N_i$, anyway.
- The sum $\sum_{j \in V} W_{i,j}$ is precisely the diagonal entry $D_{i,i}$ as it is defined in the definition of $\mathcal L$.
- In general, the quadratic form $\mathbf x^{\mathsf T}\!A \mathbf y$ can be written as a sum $\sum_i \sum_j A_{ij} x_i y_j$. If $A$ is a diagonal matrix, most terms vanish and we are left with just $\sum_i A_{ii} x_i y_i$.